# How to create a document with a table of contents in Scrivener on Windows?

Tags: scrivener

I'm using Scrivener under Windows to write a text.

How am I supposed to generate a document (Word, OpenOffice.org, LaTeX or something else) with a table of contents?

I found some tutorials for doing this on the Mac version of Scrivener, but I'm working under Windows.

Comment: it doesn't work for windows according to this post http://www.disruptiveproactivity.com/2011/11/tables-of-contents-in-scrivener/

Comment: Isn't there no workaround at all? Can I, for example, export my text to MMD and then to LaTeX?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Scrivener, I googled for you and that's what I found, maybe someone else would give a much better answer. However, If I was in your place, I would generate a word document and then add the table of content using Microsoft word, and then convert it to whatever format I want

Comment: AFAIK Scrivener does not mark sections headings as such when exporting to Word. Now I've tried to export the Scrivener text to LaTeX and edit it using the WriteLaTeX service. There are some problems, so now I'm waiting for the response of their support team.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5r9zXc6tyg

Answer (score 1):

From the [Scrivener for Windows documentation](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/documentation/scrivener-manual-win-a4.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> If you need your work to enter a standard word processor workflow, this will be your go-to method. MultiMarkdown's ODF support is comprehensive [... meaning the document can] **use the table of contents feature of a word processor.** It represents **the only output method in Scrivener that offers this support**, making MMD an enticing option for those who do not mind learning how to use it.

The documentation goes on to explain that LibreOffice (and OpenOffice, with the correct update installed) supports this format, and from there you can convert to other popular formats.

So (as I understand it) the process should be:

1. Convert to OpenDocument Format, resulting in a `.fodt` file.
2. Open in LibreOffice, and create table of contents.
3. Export to format of your choosing.

Comment: When I export the text to FODT, the headers aren't marked as such. Therefore, when I try to generate the table of contents in LibreOffice it's empty.